# Dispose of a JDialog's child JDialog the next time the parent dialog is shown

Tags: java, user-interface

I have a parent JDialog opened from button on a JFrame. The parent JDialog itself has a child JDialog that is opened from a button on the parent dialog.  When I close the parent dialog and open it again using the button on the frame, I do not want to child dialog to also open.

Is there a way to prevent the child dialog from opening, unless the user explicitly presses on the button on the parent dialog?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MultiDialog {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    final JDialog d1 = new JDialog();
                    final JDialog d2 = new JDialog(d1);
                    d1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
                    d2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

                    d1.setSize(new Dimension(150, 100));
                    d1.setTitle("Parent");
                    d1.setLocation(50, 50);

                    d2.setTitle("Child");
                    d2.setSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
                    d2.setLocation(150, 150);

                    JFrame f = new JFrame("App");
                    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    JButton b1 = new JButton("Show Parent Dialog");
                    f.add(b1);
                    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            d1.setVisible(true);
                        }
                    });

                    JButton b2 = new JButton("Show Child Dialog");
                    d1.add(b2);
                    b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            d2.setVisible(true);
                        }
                    });

                    f.pack();
                    f.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you close the child dialog when the parent dialog closes? `addWindowStateListener()` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `WindowListener` to your Parent `JDialog` and use the `windowClosing` method by overiding it.

From now on, when you're closing the Parent, the Child's `visible` attribute becomes false until we're clicking on the Parent's button again.

```
d1.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
        d2.setVisible(false);
    };
});
```

---

### Full Code

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class MultiDialog {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        final JDialog d1 = new JDialog();
                        final JDialog d2 = new JDialog(d1);
                        d1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
                        d2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

                        d1.setSize(new Dimension(150, 100));
                        d1.setTitle("Parent");
                        d1.setLocation(50, 50);

                        d2.setTitle("Child");
                        d2.setSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
                        d2.setLocation(150, 150);

                        JFrame f = new JFrame("App");
                        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                        JButton b1 = new JButton("Show Parent Dialog");
                        f.add(b1);
                        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                d1.setVisible(true);
                            }
                        });

                        d1.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
                            @Override
                            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
                                d2.setVisible(false);
                            };
                        });

                        JButton b2 = new JButton("Show Child Dialog");
                        d1.add(b2);
                        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                d2.setVisible(true);
                            }
                        });

                        f.pack();
                        f.setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
                );
    }
}
```